# I have ten classification models that need to be consolidated into 1

Tags: classification, python, ensemble-learning

As the title states, I have 10 classification models that I need to consolidate into one, more effective model. They are as follows:

```
<class 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression'> Score:  0.922902494331
<class 'sklearn.svm.classes.SVC'> Score:  0.924522189828
<class 'sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis'> Score:  0.889536767088
<class 'sklearn.svm.classes.SVC'> Score:  0.924522189828
<class 'sklearn.discriminant_analysis.QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis'> Score:  0.820213799806
<class 'sklearn.tree.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier'> Score:  0.782960803369
<class 'sklearn.tree.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier'> Score:  0.782960803369
<class 'sklearn.tree.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier'> Score:  0.782960803369
<class 'sklearn.tree.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier'> Score:  0.782960803369
<class 'sklearn.tree.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier'> Score:  0.782960803369
```

I've heard of "mixture of experts" but all of the research i've done so far points me to some more complex neural network based approaches which is beyond my comprehension at this point.

If you could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is commonly called `Ensembling`. Here's a [link](http://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/) on some ensembling techniques that you might want to try.

For simplicity's sake, a simple ensembling approach would be to perform a **majority vote**. That is, for a classification task with options `1` or `0`, and you have 10 models, just count total number of `1s` and `0s`. Another would be **averaging the probabilities for each model** and from the resulting probability, get the corresponding prediction.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed, ensemble methods are a good way to aggregate classifiers. Note that most ensemble methods also construct the classifiers and do n't take them as given. You can take Adboost weighting method and apply it on your set of classifiers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept of taking a probability and gathering predictions. Can you elaborate on that? Also, @DanLevin, I'll give that a shot as well. I found an sklearn package for Adboosting that seems like it may be useful.

Comment: Since I believe you are using sklearn for your predictions, you can use the method `predict_proba()` to get the probabilities instead of 1 or 0 prediction that you get using `predict()` method.

Comment: For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost. Please note that since your classifiers are given you cannot use AdaBoost straight forward.

Comment: Where did you get these classifiers from? Do they all relate to the same data set? If so you can treat them all as features and build a classifier up on them.

Comment: @DanLevin They do, they were all given from `models = np.load('models.npy')` Would I treat the fitted models as features or their predictions?

Comment: The predictions. I see that you are getting a score. If it is a binary classification the the score is a measure of probability of belonging to the positive class, then you can use it as is. In case of a multi class problem you should provide information about the probability of each class.

Comment: So I'll have a list of arrays, each array containing predictions. I'm not sure how I would input that into another classification model.

Comment: @madsthaks, you can feed the predictions to another model as if they are features.